# Gradient boosting algorithm example

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, xgboost

I'm trying to fully understand the gradient boosting (GB) method. I've read some wiki pages and papers about it, but it would really help me to see a full simple example carried out step-by-step. Can anyone provide one for me, or give me a link to such an example? Straightforward source code without tricky optimizations will also meet my needs.

Comment: https://medium.com/mlreview/gradient-boosting-from-scratch-1e317ae4587d Good article I came across to get overview about Gradient Boosting. Python implementation for the same using sklearn library
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/quick-introduction-boosting-algorithms-machine-learning/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to construct the following simple example (mostly for my self-understanding) which I hope could be useful for you. If someone else notices any mistake please let me know. This is somehow based on the following nice explanation of gradient boosting http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/

The example aims to predict salary per month (in dollars) based on whether or not the observation has own house, own car and own family/children. Suppose we have a dataset of three observations where the first variable is 'have own house', the second is 'have own car' and the third variable is 'have family/children', and target is 'salary per month'. The observations are

1.- (Yes,Yes, Yes, 10000)

2.-(No, No, No, 25)

3.-(Yes,No,No,5000)

Choose a number $M$ of boosting stages, say $M=1$. The first step of gradient boosting algorithm is to start with an initial model $F_{0}$. This model is a constant defined by $\mathrm{arg min}_{\gamma}\sum_{i=1}^3L(y_{i},\gamma)$ in our case, where $L$ is the loss function. Suppose that we are working with the usual loss function $L(y_{i},\gamma)=\frac{1}{2}(y_{i}-\gamma)^{2}$. When this is the case, this constant is equal to the mean of the outputs $y_{i}$, so in our case $\frac{10000+25+5000}{3}=5008.3$. So our initial model is $F_{0}(x)=5008.3$ (which maps every observation $x$ (e.g. (No,Yes,No)) to 5008.3.

Next we should create a new dataset, which is the previous dataset but instead of $y_{i}$ we take the residuals $r_{i0}=-\frac{\partial{L(y_{i},F_{0}(x_{i}))}}{\partial{F_{0}(x_{i})}}$. In our case, we have $r_{i0}=y_{i}-F_{0}(x_{i})=y_{i}-5008.3$. So our dataset becomes

1.- (Yes,Yes, Yes, 4991.6)

2.-(No, No, No, -4983.3)

3.-(Yes,No,No,-8.3)

The next step is to fit a base learner $h$ to this new dataset. Usually the base learner is a decision tree, so we use this.

Now assume that we constructed the following decision tree $h$. I constructed this tree using entropy and information gain formulas but probably I made some mistake, however for our purposes we can assume it's correct. For a more detailed example, please check

https://www.saedsayad.com/decision_tree.htm

The constructed tree is:

[image]

Let's call this decision tree $h_{0}$. The next step is to find a constant $\lambda_{0}=\mathrm{arg\;min}_{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{3}L(y_{i},F_{0}(x_{i})+\lambda{h_{0}(x_{i})})$. Therefore, we want a constant $\lambda$ minimizing

$C=\frac{1}{2}(10000-(5008.3+\lambda*{4991.6}))^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(25-(5008.3+\lambda(-4983.3)))^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(5000-(5008.3+\lambda(-8.3)))^{2}$.

This is where gradient descent comes in handy.

Suppose that we start at $P_{0}=0$. Choose the learning rate equal to $\eta=0.01$. We have

$\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{\lambda}}=(10000-(5008.3+\lambda*4991.6))(-4991.6)+(25-(5008.3+\lambda(-4983.3)))*4983.3+(5000-(5008.3+\lambda(-8.3)))*8.3$.

Then our next value $P_{1}$ is given by $P_{1}=0-\eta{\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{\lambda}}(0)}=0-.01(-4991.6*4991.7+4983.4*(-4983.3)+(-8.3)*8.3)$.

Repeat this step $N$ times, and suppose that the last value is $P_{N}$. If $N$ is sufficiently large and $\eta$ is sufficiently small then $\lambda:=P_{N}$ should be the value where $\sum_{i=1}^{3}L(y_{i},F_{0}(x_{i})+\lambda{h_{0}(x_{i})})$ is minimized. If this is the case, then our $\lambda_{0}$ will be equal to $P_{N}$. Just for the sake of it, suppose that $P_{N}=0.5$ (so that $\sum_{i=1}^{3}L(y_{i},F_{0}(x_{i})+\lambda{h_{0}(x_{i})})$ is minimized at $\lambda:=0.5$). Therefore, $\lambda_{0}=0.5$.

The next step is to update our initial model $F_{0}$ by $F_{1}(x):=F_{0}(x)+\lambda_{0}h_{0}(x)$. Since our number of boosting stages is just one, then this is our final model $F_{1}$.

Now suppose that I want to predict a new observation $x=$(Yes,Yes,No) (so this person does have own house and own car but no children). What is the salary per month of this person? We just compute $F_{1}(x)=F_{0}(x)+\lambda_{0}h_{0}(x)=5008.3+0.5*4991.6=7504.1$. So this person earns $7504.1 per month according to our model.

Answer (score 2):

As it states, the following presentation is a 'gentle' introduction to Gradient Boosting, I found it quite helpful when figuring out Gradient Boosting; there is a fully explained example included.

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/MLcourse/4_boosting/slides/gradient_boosting.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) is the repository where the xgboost package resides. That is from where the xgboost library for major languages like Julia, Java, R, etc are forked from.

[This](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package) is the Python implementation.

Walking through the source code (as instructed in the "How to contribute") docs would help you understand the intuition behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read xgboost docs. But I meant a bit different thing. Not the code of using a framework. But the code of the algorithm of classifier itself.

Comment: Ohh.  Thanks for letting me know :)   I guess I've misunderstood your question.  And welcome to the site!

Comment: @shda I have edited the answer with the relevant links. Do let me know if you find it useful :)

Comment: Full xgboost source is rather complicated example) But i'll give it a try